# Proper way and location to hydrate NgRx Store with AuthToken from LocalStorage

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

What's the proper RxJS/NgRx way of hydrating state from *LocalStorage*?

Say the app needs to know if user is logged in by reading AuthToken from *LocalStorage*. And this should happen as the first thing after NgRx Store has been initialized.

For this scenario, the AuthStore has an action `initAuth` whose associated Effect, with the help of a service, populates the state while reading the token from *LocalStorage*.

Currently I am dispatching `initAuth` inside `ngOnInit` of AppComponent:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    ...
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(protected readonly store$: Store<State>) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.store$.dispatch(authActions.initAuth());          
    }
}
```

But it feels that there should be a better way.

I was thinking to associate an Effect with the following `@ngrx/effects/init` action to dispatch `initAuth` (if it's possible, how it could be achieved?):

[image]

**Note**: I am not using [ngrx-store-localstorage](https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/api.md#root_effects_init) action and do anything you want in an Effect.

```
import { ofType, Actions, Effect, ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT } from '@ngrx/effects';

class InitEffects {
  @Effect()
  init$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT)
    .pipe(tap(() => window.alert('I should be shown')));

  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}
}
```

Also make sure to register this effects in a `forRoot` method, feature modules won't work.

Comment: Great, that would be an elegant solution if it worked, I'll check it.